# Changing the connection interval in a Bluez-based GATT-oriented application

Tags: linux, bluez, gatt, hci

We are currently working on an application on linux (a.o. RasPi running latest Debian Jessie) that connects to a BLE device (developed by us). This tool has evolved from cherry-picking files from the bluez (5.46) stack and adding an application layer on top. This all works quite nicely, except for the fact that connecting is incredibly slow. From the output of our tool, I understand that a truckload of messages need to be exchanged to communicate GATT services and characteristics, and each of those costs one connection interval of time. Since it is a low power device, we want the connection interval to be relatively high, and thus the high delay.

When connecting with Android BLE Scanner, I see (on the device side) that BLE Scanner manipulates the connection interval to a low value, gets all the requested data, and then sets the connection interval back to its original value. Note, btw, that neither BLE Scanner nor our Bluez-derived application take the preferred connection parameters into account.

Now I want to have our application do the same: set the connection interval to 8ms, get all info about characteristics and services, and set the connection interval back. In the Bluez stack I even find a nice function in the HCI layer for this: hci_le_conn_update.

But now the challenge: the rest of the application is built on top of the GATT functionality and even though the BLE specification defines a hierarchy between those two (with some layers in between), in code they seem absolutely independent of each other.

There are two parameters to the hci_le_conn_update function that are HCI specific: 'dd' (file descriptor to device) and 'handle' (some value that identifies the connection). The hcitool tells me that when I create a connection, the first handle is 64, so I tried with that value. For 'dd' I used hci_dev_open to get a file descriptor for the device. This worked. Sort of.

As I said before, the min/max values are not entirely taking into account. So when I set it to 6/10, I get 11 and when I set it to 6/50, I get 60. This is a bit too undeterministic for my taste, and I would prefer a function that directly changes the connection interval instead of giving a range that is mostly ignored anyway. Also the fact that I have to use a hardcoded magic number 64 gives me a bad itch. I can actually control the connection interval on the embedded device's side, but I want the control at the side of the client application.

The goal is to update the connection interval in a Bluez-GATT-based application. Within certain limits, I do not mind that much how I get there. Any suggestions?

Comment: It has been a while and it turned out that we approached this entirely the wrong way. We are now specifying the connection interval to be between 8-500ms, and let the client figure it out. We were afraid this would be very inefficient because we thought the MCU had to be awake at least once per connection interval. It turns out this is not true (BLE stack offers callbacks for signalling when we can go to sleep) and if the client decides on a connection interval of e.g. 49, then we are still good (enough).

Answer (score 0):

In the official dbus API, there is no method to change connection parameters. (See https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt and https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt). The key is therefore to send the Connection Parameter Update Request from the peripheral side. You can of course experiment with sending a raw hci command but that is a bit "hacky" and has no guarantees to not mess up the BlueZ daemon.

If you would like to discuss the features of BlueZ such as an connection parameter update request api, you should do that on the BlueZ mailing list (http://www.bluez.org/contact/) rather than here.